# How do I improve query execution parallelization for a single user in Azure SQL Datawarehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We have a new report dashboard that's loaded in our web application, where the data is sourced from Azure SQLDataWareHouse.

The dashboard is made up of ~8-10 tiles, each displaying a different metric, loaded by a different query.

The various queries are executed from the webapp using some straightforward ADO.NET code, to connect to the DW with a `dashboard` user account.

I've read both articles on [Memory & Concurrency Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/memory-concurrency-limits) and [Resource Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management) but there's something I'm just not understanding.

For our DW service level (Gen2 - DW200c), the server should support running 8 concurrent queries.
Similarly, we've added our `dashboard` user to the `staticrc80` resource group which should give it access to all 8 concurrency slots.

But this doesn't seem to help. Am I right in understanding that regardless of these resource configurations, it'll still only execute a sinlge query for a single user at a time ?
And that multiple queries executed under the same user account would still be queued up?

One alternative seems to be that I could have a different user account for each tile, 
make 8 separate connections,
run 8 seperate queries,
where each query account is assigned to the staticrc10 role.

Am I missing something fundamental here. This DW is dedicated to a single app, with a single user account reader user account. How do I configure that account in terms of resource classe etc... to make full use of the 8 paralell query/200 DWU resource allocations.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/memory-concurrency-limits#concurrency-maximums-for-resource-classes), static resource class `staticrc80` at DWU200c uses 8 resource slots, so where DWU200c has a max of 8 concurrent slots, I would expect a single connection to use all of them, and therefore your concurrent queries will queue, one at a time.

[image: static resource classes and concurrency slots]
Consider switching your user to `staticrc10` which will allow up to 8 concurrent queries.  No need to make 8 different users.

Can I ask, are you using Power BI?  Also, DWU200c is pretty low for any workload, it's really just for keeping things ticking over.

Comment: Nope. Tableau for "Operatation Reports" but we have a couple of dashboard tiles hosted in an ASP.NET MVC app that pull high level metrics/counts from the datawarehouse directly (Dapper + ADO.NET). My issue here is that I'm just not seeing the 100% utilizization of the DWU service level. we're never coming anywhere near 200 DWU. Most we ever see hit in the azure portal metrics are 50-60 and yet still the reports are dog-slow and on pages where multiple tiles are being called, they seem to be executed sequentially with each one loading one after the next.

Comment: And you're sure this is not the code executing them sequentially as per David's point?  I guess form a diagnostic point of view you could i) temporarily scale up say to 1000 see what happens, ii) reassign the user to staticrc10 see what happens etc

Comment: I went back and confirmed this locally running 4 different tests.

user account @ staticrc10 | staticrc40
executing the sprocs sequentially vs. executing them all in parallel 

In all 4 scenarios, the total exec time is ~75-80 secs. when you go to staticrc10 more run in parallel but take longer - (confirmed through the [dm_pdw_exec_requests] view)

So looks like I'm simply back to the drawing board on perf/query writing, and looking at implementing some result caching solutions.

Comment: Hmm seems a long time.  Did you try any tests at higher DWU?  We could  look at perf tuning the queries if you want to raise a separate question including DDL, sample data etc.  You may have already looked at / considered SQL DW execution plan, hash / round robin distribution, materialized views, secondary non-clustered indexes, pre-aggregating your results, the new result caching feature David mentioned, ruled out your user is not in any other resource class and so on.  I would repeat that DW200c is kind of low to be doing any kind of performance testing IMHO.

Comment: yeah that's where I'm at now. have gotten into some of the queries and there's obv. perf issues that need to be addressed. as well as everything else.

Comment: on the comment of "200c" being kinda small... that's a bit of an issue for us. this is a realtively small project with a small budget for some R&D testing on a data set that just happens to be quite large. right now, turning up the dials (even if that turns out to be the solution) will be a hard sell. a 200c DW is almost the same cost as our 1000DTU prod db so....

Comment: OK good luck.  Let me know if I can help with the tuning.  Also paging @RonDunn (MS) who's been doing great answers on SQLDW the last year or so.

Answer (score 1):

> multiple queries executed under the same user account would still be queued up?

Your observed behavior may have nothing to do with the concurrency slots.  It could be that the client is not sending all the queries in parallel.  A client connection to SQL Server (or Synapse) can only process one query at a time.  A client is free to open as many connections as it wants, but they typically don't.  Two connections per client is the most you typically see.

Stepping back, if you're working on improving performance of a dashboard, have you looked at [Result Set Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-result-set-caching-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest)?  It's intended to improve the response time for common queries, which often happens with dashboard tiles.

Comment: Thanks for this David. Result Set Caching isn't something I'd stumbled across. I'll definitely give it a look. 

Re: You're second point... we've already bottomed out the sync vs. async issue. The tiles are each loaded by seperate MVC controller calls. The calls are all using seperate connections (albeit with the same user account) but I'll ask the devs to go back and triple check that there isn't some strange synchronous behaviour going on.

Comment: I went back and confirmed this locally running 4 different tests.

user account @ staticrc10 | staticrc40
executing the sprocs sequentially vs. executing them all in parallel 

In all 4 scenarios, the total exec time is ~75-80 secs. when you go to staticrc10 more run in parallel but take longer - (confirmed through the [dm_pdw_exec_requests] view)

So looks like I'm simply back to the drawing board on perf/query writing, and looking at implementing some result caching solutions.

Comment: I would expect a dashboard solution to benefit (require lower DWU) from caching either in Synapse with summary tables/materialized views/resultset caching, or in Power BI/Azure Analysis Services.

Comment: thanks for the tip on RESULT_SET_CACHING that's made a signfiicant difference as a quick bandaid solution while we get the perf. tuning sorted out behind the scenes. much appreciated.